# Protractor to dynamically choose browser based on input

Tags: protractor

I am new to protractor and I want to be able to run my chrome browser painted or headless.

So I set up something like this

```
 let chrome = {
     browserName: 'chrome',
     platform: 'MAC',
     'max-duration': '1800',

 };

let chromeHeadless = {
     browserName: 'chrome',     
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=800,600" ]
    }
};

browserDefault = browser.params.browserToUse

exports.config = {
   params: {

    'browserToUse': "get from user'

   },
   capabilities: browserDefault,
 }
```

and i ran this code as

```
 protractor config.js --params.browserToUse='chromeHeadless'
```

But this does not work. Protractor fails saying it does not understand "browser.params.browserInput". Whats the right way to make protractor dynamically choose chrome or chromeheadless based on the input

Comment: `browser.params.browserInput`?. Can you share the console error to give a better clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global variable `browser` is only init when code run into `onPrepare()`.  You used `browser` outside `onPrepare()` function, `browser` have not been inited, it is undefined, so you met the error.

Another point you need to get it's when the variable `browser` inited, a browser window has been opened, means protractor has know which capabilities to launch the browser.  Therefore you can't use `browser.params.xxx` to specify which capabilities, you need to tell protractor the capabilities before it init the `browser` variable.

```
let capabilitiesMap = {
    'chrome-headful' : {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        platform: 'MAC',
        'max-duration': '1800',   
    },

    'chrome-headless': {
        browserName: 'chrome',     
        chromeOptions: {
          args: [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=800,600" ]
        }
    }
};

let browserToUse = 'chrome-headful'; // set default value

// extract the browserToUse value from cli
process.argv.slice(3).forEach(function(arg) {
    var name = arg.split('=')[0];
    var value = arg.split('=')[1];
    var name = name.replace('--', '');

    if (name === 'browserToUse') {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(capabilitiesMap, value) ) {
            browserToUse = value;
        }
    } 
});


let config = {

    seleniumAddress: '',
    specs: [],
    onPrepare: function() {}

};

config.capabilities = capabilitiesMap[browserToUse];

exports.config = config;
```

CLI example: `protractor conf.js --browserToUse=chrome-headless`

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this issue and soleved it using the `getMultiCapabilities()` function in your conf.js

```
const _ = require('lodash');    
 let capabilities = {

   chrome: {
     browserName: 'chrome',
     platform: 'MAC',
     'max-duration': '1800',

 },

chromeHeadless : {
     browserName: 'chrome',     
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=800,600" ]
    }
}

}
getMultiCapabilities() {
    const browsers = this.params.browserToUse.split(',');//if you pass more than one browser e.g chrome,chromeHeadless
    const cap = _(capabilities).pick(browsers).values().value(); //this uses the lodash npm module
    return cap;
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

In a testing context working with just Chrome, I did the following. In capabilities:

```
chromeOptions: {
   args: []
```

}

```
 beforeLaunch: function() {
    //at this point browser is not yet defined, so process command line directly
  if (process.argv[process.argv.length-1].search('headless=true')>-1){
      config.capabilities.chromeOptions.args.push("--headless");
      config.capabilities.chromeOptions.args.push("--disable-gpu");
      config.capabilities.chromeOptions.args.push("--window-size=1600,1000");
    }  
  }
```

That way by the time the browser was launched, it had the right configuration. Where I have "headless=true", you might want "Chrome-headless."
And then on the command line I call it like you do with `--params.headless=false`so that should I want to find it in the script itself later (after the browser has launched), it is readily available.

Note I had just one command line parameter and control of the command line, so it felt okay to assume this parameter was the last.